# What is the 'time' in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, time, jupyter-notebook, ipython

What's the type of `time` in jupyter notebook? Variable or function?

Below is my tests using python code.

Test 1:
[image]

Test 2:
[image]

Test 3:
[image]

Test 4:
[image]

Test 5:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`time`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-time) (or more properly, `%time`), is an IPython [magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) - a command that is otherwise not available directly in Python. As I noted, they are typically prefixed with `%` or `%%` - `%` is for line magics, `%%` is for cell magics. If the [automagic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-automagic) option is on, line magics can also be executed without the `%` character.

The `()` is not part of the IPython magic syntax. When you wrote `time()`, you were timing the expression `()`, which evaluates to an empty tuple.

IPython magic return values, if any, can be assigned to variables, but only when invoked with the `%` prefix:

```
a = %time
```

However, `%time` does not have a typical return value, so in the above example, `a` will be `None`.